# Cordova camera capture photo problem after visit another route

Tags: cordova, phonegap, html-framework-7, cordova-plugin-camera

i use a button to capture photo,
it works fine,
but i'm unable to capture photo after visit another link/route.
here is my code sample:

```
document.getElementById("imageCapture").addEventListener("click", imageCapture);
function imageCapture() { 
//code for camera take picture
}
```

is there any page:init or any other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple:
just call the eventListener function on page:init